# Why do I get InvalidDataException installing from local Nuget.Server?

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-server

So I installed a local NuGet server using the NuGet.Server package and VS2012.  Everything seems to work fine, I have a package that I created based on a web application.  The server knows about the package (i.e. I can list it using "nuget list"), but when I try to install it on the target machine, I get an InvalidDataException with a message the the Archive file cannot be size 0.

I am using Win7 x86 and the command-line nuget.exe utility from within PowerShell.  Nuget.exe is in \windows.

Also, I can install packages from the public nuget.org server on this target machine.

In an interesting twist, I am able to install the very same internal package from the very same internal server when I run the same command from within the Package Manager Console in VS2012.  I have verified that the nuget.exe versions are the same.

Any help on this?

Thanks,
Matthew

Comment: I recommend setting up a Fiddler proxy to check the traffic between nuget and your nuget webservice.

Comment: I just did that, but I don't really know what I'm looking for.  The results from my workstation that installs the package correctly looks exactly like from the test machine that doesn't.

Comment: Have you considered a third-party server like ProGet (http://inedo.com/proget)? It's free and will likely not give these errors. (disclaimer: I work for Inedo)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was an issue with the local Nuget cache.  Once I cleared it out, the package installed correctly.